# PDF to PDF/X conversion .NET

Tags: pdf, document-converter

I'm looking for a .NET library (preferably free/open source) or a command line tool to programmatically convert ordinary PDF (or PDF/A if that's easier) files to PDF/X-1a (2001 or 2003) for print processing.

Must be something that can be used locally (no web service or cloud) and run preferably under MS Windows.

I know that Aspose.Pdf can do this but would like to have more (also cheaper) possibilities to achieve this.

I will also try to convert via Ghostscript since I found a stackoverflow issue pointing to that possibility.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The [Spire.PDF for .NET](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/pdf-for-net-introduce.html) library (paid) provides the capability to convert PDF to PDF/X-1a. You can install it via NuGet:

```
PM> Install-Package Spire.PDF
```

Next, you can use the **PdfStandardsConverter** class to convert PDF to PDF/X-1a:

```
PdfStandardsConverter converter = new PdfStandardsConverter(inputFilePath);
converter.ToPdfX1A2001(outputFilePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Syncfusion PDF Library](https://www.syncfusion.com/pdf-framework/net). It offers PDF viewer controls to view, review, and print PDF files. Its powerful conversion APIs make it easy to convert HTML, Word, Excel, PowerPoint, and images to PDF.

https://www.syncfusion.com/pdf-framework/net/pdf-library/edit-pdf.

The whole suite of controls is available for free (commercial applications also) through the community license program if you qualify. The community license is the full product with no limitations or watermarks.

https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense

Note: I work for Syncfusion.